# Selecting RawContacts with special requirements in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

**Whenever I want to add new data to an existing Android contact, I use the following function to retrieve all `RawContacts` IDs for the given contact ID:**

```
protected ArrayList<Long> getRawContactID(String contact_id) {
    ArrayList<Long> rawContactIDs = new ArrayList<Long>();
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID };
    String where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selection = new String[] { contact_id };
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, selection, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            rawContactIDs.add(c.getLong(0));
        }
    }
    finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return rawContactIDs;
}
```

After that, I just insert the data using the `ContentResolver`:

`getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);`

This is done for all `RawContacts` IDs that have been found previously. The effect is, of course, that all data is added repeatedly. Thus I want to return only one result now, but this has to meet special requirements.

**I would like to adjust my function above so that its result meets the following requirements:**

1. `ContactsContract.RawContactsColumn.DELETED` must be 0
2. The `RawContacts` entry must not be a secured one like Facebook's
3. `ContactsContract.SyncColumns.ACCOUNT_TYPE` is preferably "com.google". So if there is one entry that meets this requirement, it should be returned. If there is none, return any of the remaining entries.

How can I do this (most efficiently)? I don't want to make the query to complex.

Comment: Why not use a sync adapter with your own account, and place data into that account ? that should give you the control you are looking for

Comment: Thank you! The advantage is: If you can add it to a Google raw contact, it is automatically synced with all the contact's data to Google contacts (normally, if sync is on). If I create my own account plus sync adapter, I would need to request several additional permissions and I would have to implement the synchronization to some servers manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this some thought, from my experience with contact r/w, and with your needs in mind. I hope this helps you solve the issue and or points you in the direction you are looking for.
Please note that i have no device available with any sync adapters such as facebook so unfortunately i cannot confirm my answer viability (the read only bit mainly which might changeable to a simple != '' ).

Same `getRawContactID` function with some adjustments

```
protected ArrayList<Long> getRawContactID(String contact_id) {
    HashMap<String,Long> rawContactIDs = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE };
    String where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.DELETED + " != 1 AND " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.RAW_CONTACT_IS_READ_ONLY + " != 1" ;
    String[] selection = new String[] { contact_id };
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, selection, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            rawContactIDs.put(c.getString(1),c.getLong(0));
        }
    }
    finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return getBestRawID(rawContactIDs);
}
```

And another `getBestRawID` function to find the best suited account -

```
protected ArrayList<Long> getBestRawID(Map<String,Long> rawContactIDs)
{
    ArrayList<Long> out = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (String key : rawContactIDs.KeySet())
    {
       if (key.equals("com.google"))
       {
          out.clear(); // might be better to seperate handling of this to another function to prevent WW3.
          out.add(rawContactIDs.get(key));
          return out;
       } else {
          out.add(rawContactIDs.get(key));
       }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Also note - I wrote most of the code without running / testing it. Apologies in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything seems to work really well :) But I don't understand your comment in the second piece of code. What's the problem with clearing that list at that point?

Comment: It just isn't very much scalable or dynamic, for example if you want to change stuff in the future.

Comment: Okay, finally found out that `ContactsContract.RawContacts.RAW_CONTACT_IS_READ_ONLY` has been introduced in API level 11. Found that when the app kept crashing for thousands of users (my minimum API level is 8). Somehow Eclipse didn't warn me about that. Is there any alternative for API levels < 11 or does that mean all raw contacts were writable before API level 11?

Comment: Ouch, i can't see any alternative to that column, i guess that it only applies to api 11 (i also believe that's when the facebook account adapters were blocked from r/w)

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess as well. So the Facebook adapter was writable before API level 11? Do you know that fore sure - for any API level prior to 11?

Comment: Don't know for sure, so don't want to mislead you - but i remember that it was changed at some later point